# Posting Soap XML in Windows 8 Metro App - Errors

Tags: c#, xml, soap, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am writing C# code for a WinRT Surface Tablet in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8.  Although my xml is formatted (I am porting from apps on other platforms that work fine) I am apparently having trouble with the request syntax.

I've been trying several different approaches and hit dead ends with the limitation of windows store apps in methods.  The last I have tried is using HttpClient, HttpContent and HttpRequestMessage:  (omitting the actual xml and urls, obviously)

```
string xmlSOAP = "..............[my soap xml]................."
string url = "http://example.domain.com/myMagicalwebservice.asmx"
string SOAPAction = "www.blahblah.com/doXMLStuff";

HttpClient hc = new 

HttpContent content = new String Content(xmlSOAP);

HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", SOAPAction);
req.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
req.Content = content;
req.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");

hc.SendAsync(req).ContinueWith(responseTask =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(responseTask.Result);
});
```

This results in a System.FormatException of "The format of value 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8' is invalid."

If I instead add the content type directly to the HttpContent instead of to HttpRequestMessage, I get the same outcome.

If I simply comment out the line adding the content type (just doing dumb trial and error here) I receive a result with statuscode 415: "Unsupported Media Type."

I have tried posting using the PostAsync method of HttpClient but I am unsure how to get the response using that.

Any help would be very much appreciated, and I thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Your code above doesn't seem to use the xmlSOAP variable anywhere. Are you actually sending any XML?

Comment: @chue x, OOPS, I accidentally omitted that in my post but it is in my code.  I add it using the Content method.  I will update my example code when I get back to my main computer...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up chute x, I updated the sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
req.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: This works.  I was trying to run this within an async method, and what you suggest is not available in such a method.  Thank you.